# How can i find certain types of buildings in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap

i'm trying to make a list of all the police stations that are in OpenStreetMap.org so i can compare it with mine (a full one with all the police stations in the country) and add the ones that are not there. at the moment i'm doing it one by one, searching from my list and if it is not in the map i add it. but i want to now if there is a way to make the map show me all the police stations that are in a country or a region. if someone who knows about OSM could help me that would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can use e.g. Overpass to query OpenStreetMap for features. Here is the query that you need to retrieve all police stations.

```
/*
 This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
 The original search was:
 “amenity=police”
 */
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=police”
 node["amenity"="police"]({{bbox}});
 way["amenity"="police"]({{bbox}});
 relation["amenity"="police"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

You can run the query with Overpass Turbo, [here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/9IH). First position the map over the area you are interested in, then press "Run".

You can use any of the export options to download the results, instead of viewing them on the map

I forgot to mention that a police station is not really a building type in OpenStreetMap, it is considered an amenity. More information about the correct tagging can be found on the [OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features), but this system does not allow me to post more links to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

To find the policestations you can use e.g. OverPass-API (I recommend [TURBO](http://overpass-turbo.eu/)). The more complex way is to use the [planet.osm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) dump / extracts and process it using filterers (e.g. osmosis). Last one is more complex, but allows you to controll the area more precise.

Please be aware that building is the wrong feature. Some mappers prefer to map the amenity / usage as a seperate POI and some policestations are mapped as are for the whole site of the station. Be also aware that the community is skeptical about [imports](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import) and quality of external datasets.